# parsing Json in swift4

Tags: json, swift4, codable

hello i try to decode Json:

> {"result":[
>       {"ID":"80",
>       "time":"09:00:00",
>       "status":[
>   {"status":0,"kirpeja_id":"74","name":"Natalja","image":"natalija255.png","duration":"00:20:00"},
>   {"status":1,"kirpeja_id":"80","name":"Lina","image":"kazkas.png","duration":"00:30:00"},
>   {"status":0,"kirpeja_id":"82","name":"Rasa ","image":"IMG_20170906_171553.jpg","duration":"00:40:00"}
>               ]},
>       {"ID":"81",
>       "time":"09:10:00",
>       "status":[
>   {"status":0,"kirpeja_id":"66","name":"Ilona","image":"ilona_new.jpg","duration":"00:30:00"},
>   {"status":0,"kirpeja_id":"74","name":"Natalja","image":"natalija255.png","duration":"00:20:00"},
>   {"status":0,"kirpeja_id":"80","name":"Lina","image":"kazkas.png","duration":"00:30:00"},
>   {"status":0,"kirpeja_id":"82","name":"Rasa ","image":"IMG_20170906_171553.jpg","duration":"00:40:00"}
>               ]},
>   ...

here my classes

```
class TimeStatusResult: Codable {
let result: [TimeStatus]
init (result:[TimeStatus]) {
self.result = result
}
}
class TimeStatus: Codable {
let ID:String?
let time: String?
let status: [Status]
init (status:[Status]) {
    self.ID = ""
    self.time = ""
    self.status = status
}
}
class Status: Codable {
let status: String?
let kirpeja_id: String?
let name: String?
let image: String?
let duration: String?
init () {
    self.status = ""
    self.kirpeja_id = ""
    self.name = ""
    self.image = "nophoto.jpg"
    self.duration = ""
}
}
```

here my json function

```
final let jsonUrl = URL(string: "http://**********/getlaikas_new.php")
private var timeStatusResult = [TimeStatus]()

 func downloadJson () {
    guard let downloadURL = jsonUrl else {return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: downloadURL)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "data=\(pInfo.paslaugosData!)&salonId=\(pInfo.ID!)&paslaugos_id=\(pInfo.paslaugosId!)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, urlResponse, error in

        guard let data = data , error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print ("something wrong")
            return }
        print ("downloaded!")
        do
        {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            print (data)
            let downloadedTimeStatus = try decoder.decode(TimeStatusResult.self, from: data)

            self.timeStatusResult = downloadedTimeStatus.result

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               // self.kirpejosPaslaugosTable.reloadData()
            }

        } catch {
            print ("something wrong after download")
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

in this line i have issue

```
let downloadedTimeStatus = try decoder.decode(TimeStatusResult.self, from: data)
```

somebody can help me? :(

Comment: What's the issue? Wrong data? Crash? Won't compile?

Comment: after than line code goes to catch statement and variable downloadedTimeStatus is empty

Comment: Why don't you print the **real** error in the `catch` clause rather than a meaningless literal string?

Comment: Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [burzua_1.TimeStatusResult.(CodingKeys in _479ABD1AF7892C9F2FD23EC23214E088).result, Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)), burzua_1.TimeStatus.(CodingKeys in _479ABD1AF7892C9F2FD23EC23214E088).status, Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)), burzua_1.Status.(CodingKeys in _479ABD1AF7892C9F2FD23EC23214E088).status], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very clear:

> ...burzua_1.**Status.(CodingKeys** in _479ABD1AF7892C9F2FD23EC23214E088).**status**], debugDescription: "**Expected to decode String but found a number instead.**"

The value for key `status` is **not** in double quotes so it's an `Int`

```
class Status: Codable {
   let status: Int
   ...
```

Please don't declare all properties carelessly as optional. For example `status` as well as all other keys is present in all `Status` dictionaries.

Comment: shame for me :) tnx